# react-stomp connection delay and raise error with sprint boot websocket and zuul api gateway

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, spring-websocket, stomp, netflix-zuul

When connecting directly to spring boot WebSocket url, there is no issue and pretty fast. But if connecting through zuul api-gateway url, there is a significant delay in connection and raise errors.

front end error:
[image]

code(the URL is api-gateway url):
[image]
backend error:
[image]

WebSocket config:
[image]

api-gateway config:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I double-checked dependencies, the spring-zuul's version is 2.2.1 but the zuul-core it wrapped has version 1.3.1, which does not support ws. It's hard to notice, I am considering to switch to spring cloud gateway.